# How to pass JSON data object {items.symbol} value to another class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api, send

I am using React js. I have a class Stock.js where I am fetching an API and displaying the data on the web page in the form of table.
When I click on the table data (table data are links) It sends the `item.symbol` to `onhandleclick()` method. For example:

| Symbol | Age |
| --- | --- |
| X | 20 |
| Y | 22 |

So the values in symbol table are referred as `item.symbol`
Here if I click on <kbd>X</kbd> it sends the value `X` to `onhandleclick()` and now I want to send  this value `X` or `Y` whichever user clicks on to another class. By another class I mean let's say I have a class `xyz.js` I want to send the value of `item.symbol` to class `xyz.js` so I can use this value and do whatever I want with that value in my `xyz.js` class. Is there a way to do it?

My code: (Stock.js)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Symbols from "./Symbols";

export default class Stocks extends Component {
  

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false,
     symbolsname: "",
    };
  }


  handleClick(symbol) {
      //pass the value to another class here
  }

  componentDidMount(symbol) {
    fetch("http://131.181.190.87:3001/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: json,
       
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    
    let filteredItems = this.state.items.filter((item) => {
      return (
        item.symbol.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toUpperCase()) !==
          -1 || item.industry.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1
      );
    });
    var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          
          <table border={2} cellPadding={1}>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Industry</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              {filteredItems.map((item) => (
                <tr>
                  <Link to="/symbols">
                    <td
                      key={item.symbol}
                      onClick={() => this.onhandleclick(item.symbol)} //here I am passing the value of item.symbol to onhandleclick()
                    >
                      {item.symbol}
                    </td>
                  </Link>

                  <td key={item.name}>{item.name}</td>
                  <td key={item.industry}>{item.industry}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
              }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

After doing what  `maniraj-murugan`said in the answers, it says undefined, so I have uploaded the screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by ```another class``` class here?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Please have a look I have updated my question

Comment: Do you need to send as params while redirecting here ? ```<Link to="/symbols">``` or you need to send data to different file??

Comment: I need to send the data to `symbols.js` file. for example if there is value `X` or `Y` or whatever is there in the table data of symbol section it sends that to `symbols.js`

Comment: you'll need to define handleClick on a parent component who will receive the value and trigger an event on your 'other class' passing the value in. If you want a shared state in your app I suggest you have a look at Redux js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect to `symbol.js` using `history.push` with click event handler like, (Remove `Link` tag here) So change,

```
    <Link to="/symbols">
      <td key={item.symbol} onClick={() => this.onhandleclick(item.symbol)} //here I am passing the value of item.symbol to onhandleclick()>
            {item.symbol}
      </td>
   </Link>
```

**to,**

```
<td key={0} onClick={() => this.onhandleclick(item.symbol)} 
style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "blue" }}
 >
   {item.symbol}
</td>
```

And `onHandleClick` function like,

```
onhandleclick(data) {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push({
      pathname: "/Symbol",
      symbol: data
    });
  }
```

Here the second property is props that you can pass which is symbol in your case so you can give it like, `symbol: data` ..

> **Working Sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v4-withrouter-demo-2luvr

**Update:**
-> After the update from OP , there are some changes that have been made.

> => import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"; in the main component `index.js` where you are initializing the parent component in the call to ReactDOM.render .

**index.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

**stocks.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Symbols from "./Symbols";

const filteredItems = [
  { symbol: "X", name: "item1", industry: "industry1" },
  { symbol: "Y", name: "item2", industry: "industry2" }
];

export default class Stocks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      search: "",
      symbol: ""
    };
  }

  updateSearch(event) {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value });
  }

  onhandleclick(data) {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push({
      pathname: "/Symbols",
      symbol: data
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form-for-table-search">
          Search symbol or industry: &emsp;
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.search}
            onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
          />
          &emsp; &emsp;{" "}
          <button type="button" className="btn-submit">
            Search
          </button>
          <br />
        </form>
        <table border={2} cellPadding={1}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Symbol</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Industry</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {filteredItems.map((item, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td
                  key={0}
                  onClick={() => this.onhandleclick(item.symbol)} //here I am passing the value of item.symbol to onhandleclick()
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "blue" }}
                >
                  {item.symbol}
                </td>

                <td key={item.name}>{item.name}</td>
                <td key={item.industry}>{item.industry}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Symbols.js:**

```
import React from "react";

export default class Symbol extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("came here", this.props.location.symbol);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Symbol value: {this.props.location.symbol}</div>;
  }
}
```

**[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hamilton-5fziw)**

Comment: I was wondering what is `location` here in render()?Since it says undefined when I run and I believe it has to do with `location` since I don't have anything named `location`

Comment: @Hemlata, ```location``` is the location object that represents the current URL.. You can see it in the codesandbox I have provided in solution and it works exactly what you want.. To retrieve the symbol value, you need to get it using the ```this.props.location``` which you have passed during ```history.push``` ..

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-fog-t0hmq?file=/src/Stocks.js

Comment: I have added my codesandbox. When I run it it says undefined in the complier. Could you please have a look what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it gives error in sandbox since you don't have access to my api, but on my computer it works I can upload the screenshot in my question in a moment

Comment: @Hemlata, The straight forward error is there is no ```App``` component but you are referring to it.. Fix that error first..

Comment: I do have a class App.js but I only uploaded my main two class. Let me upload all of them

Comment: I have uploaded all of them and there is no error on sandbox  so please have a look

Comment: @Hemlata, It would work in your local because you have different file path and I believe there you are having separate ```components``` as folder and you have files inside it.. So unless you make effort to provide complete working example it is hard to give you clear solution.. Already spent enough time for you in giving solution..

Comment: Yes I have added the code again  Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-fog-t0hmq?file=/src/Symbols.js I have added all the main code again. There are errors but I am not sure how to fix them as they work in my computer. But its all my code that you might need. Please have a look

Comment: @Hemlata, Here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hamilton-5fziw .. Hope this is all you want. I have hardcoded ```filteredItems``` which would be an API in your application.. Also removed some code related to API and state management which you could add it from your local..

Comment: Thanks!! It works. Could you update some of the code in your answer so I can upvote?

Comment: @Hemlata, I have updated the question with exact changes made and do refer to the sandbox for better understanding.. Don't forget to accept the solution by marking the tick below voting arrow..

Answer (score 0):

You could export a function from `Symbol.js` and use that in `handleClick`.

```
// Symbol.js
export default class Symbol {
  doSomething(symbol) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

```
// Stocks.js
import Symbol from 'Symbol.js';

handleClick(symbol) {
  Symbol.doSomething(symbol);
};
```

Comment: What does `(props.onClick) === "function")` means here? Why do I need to compare it to `function`?

Comment: It checks that there actually is an `onClick` function provided, since react doesn't force you to provide one. If this line wasn't there, it would throw an error when you don't provide one and try to execute it.

Comment: When I write `export const clickHandler = () => {
  // Do something
};` It gives an error the export module can only be used in typescript file. I pasted that after the `export default class Symbols extends React.Component {`

Comment: This is not working for me. I am using react.js and I think the code you wrote is different. Or maybe write the whole code for it please so it's easy to understand

Comment: @Hemlata My initial answer was for react as well but using the function component syntax which is shorter to read. I edited my answer to better reflect the approach that would probably work for you

Comment: I tried that and it says `×
TypeError: _Symbols__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.doSomething is not a function` for this line ` Symbol.doSomething(symbol);`